# How to handle several post request at the same time

Tags: node.js

I need to handle POST requests from my GPS Provider (Trucking company) so that a light blinks for X seconds using Raspberry Pi GPIO + Relay when a truck breaks certain rule.

I have the following problem:
When I receive more than one POST request at the same time the blinker overlaps, which I dont want. I want the POST request that are received while the blinker is oon to be ignored.

Here is the code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var myParser = require("body-parser");
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var moment = require('moment');
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio, // Constructor function for Gpio objects.
  led1 = new Gpio(4, 'out'),         // Export GPIO17 as an output.
  led2 = new Gpio(17, 'out'),
  iv;
var busy = 0;
console.log("Inicio " + busy);

led1.writeSync(0);
led2.writeSync(0);

app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

function timestamp(fecha, hora){
  var a = new Date(fecha + ' ' + hora);
  return moment(a,'MMM, DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss a', false).add(-6,'hour').format('DD/MM/YY HH:mm');
}

function unidad(device){
  var res = device.split(" ");
  return res[0];
}

//ALERTA ROJA
app.post("/geotab/alerta_roja/", function(request, response) {
    if (busy == 0) {
        busy = 1;
    console.log(busy);
        response.send("200");
        console.log("--Alerta Roja-- " + request.body.duracion);
        io.emit('chat message', timestamp(request.body.fecha, request.body.hora) + " : Alerta Roja - " + request.body.regla);

        iv = setInterval(function () {
            led1.writeSync(led1.readSync() ^ 1); // 1 = on, 0 = off :)
        }, 200);

        setTimeout(function () {
         clearInterval(iv); // Stop blinking
        led1.writeSync(0);  // Turn LED off.
        // led.unexport();    // Unexport GPIO and free resources
        }, 1000 * request.body.duracion);
    busy = 0;
    console.log(busy);
    } else {
    console.log("Ocupada");
    }
});

//ALERTA AMARILLA
app.post("/geotab/alerta_amarilla/", function(request, response) {
    response.send("200");
    console.log("--Alerta Amarilla-- " + request.body.duracion);
    io.emit('chat message', timestamp(request.body.fecha, request.body.hora) + " : Alerta Amarilla - " + request.body.regla);

    iv = setInterval(function () {
        led2.writeSync(led2.readSync() ^ 1); // 1 = on, 0 = off :)
       }, 200);

    setTimeout(function () {
       clearInterval(iv); // Stop blinking
    led2.writeSync(0);  // Turn LED off.
    // led.unexport();    // Unexport GPIO and free resources
    }, 1000 * request.body.duracion);
});

app.get('/',function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  led.writeSync(0);  // Turn LED off.
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('Usuario Conectado');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  LED.writeSync(0); // Turn LED off
  LED.unexport(); // Unexport GPIO to free resources 
 console.log('Usuario Desconectado');
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Escuchando en puerto 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to keep a flag in your server that tells you whether the LED is currently being blinked.  And, if that flag is set, you ignore any other operations that want to initiate a blink.

If you encapsulate your blink logic into one single function that everyone calls, then you can set, clear and check that flag all in that one function.

For example, you could have this function to control led1:

```
let currentlyBlinking = false;
let led1Interval;

function initiateBlink(blinkDuration = 5000, blinkInterval = 500) {
    if (!currentlyBlinking) {
        currentlyBlinking = true;

        // stop blinking after blinkDuration
        setTimeout(stopBlink, blinkDuration);

        // turn on initially, then toggle afterwards
        led1.writeSync(1);
        led1Interval = setInterval(() => {
            led1.writeSync(led1.readSync() ^ 1); // 1 = on, 0 = off :)
        }, blinkInterval);
    }

}

function stopBlink() {
    clearInterval(led1Interval);
    currentlyBlinking = false;
    led1.writeSync(0);
}
```

Then, don't access `led1` directly anywhere in your code.  Only use these functions to initiate a blink or to stop a current blink.  If you had multiple LEDs that all had similar functionality, you could encapsulate this in a simple object and just create an object for each LED and the state for that LED would be instance variables of each object.

If you have access to asynchronous read/write operations, those would be preferable from a scale point of view.